# I need to recreate/convert two designs respecting color blindness. Where to start?

Tags: color, color-conversion, affinity-designer

I have a design made with RGB for digital platforms and the same design made in CMYK for printing.

Now, I have to recreate both designs respecting Deuteranomaly, Protanomaly and Monochromatic.

Where should I start? Google did not help much - which made me come here - I figure I might be searching for the wrong terms.

---

I do not look forward to have "one size fits all". This was made for a school, and teachers will handle these to normal vision and color blinded students. Basically, I should have 4 files for each design.

---

I think Monochromatic could be the easiest, converting everything to Black and White and increasing contrast. What about the rest?

Tool I’m using: Affinity Designer

Comment: You can simulate the two most common types of colorblindnesses in photoshop, indesign and illustrator. But nothing can be done to help you of you dont tell what tool you are using.

Comment: OP edited to clarify tool used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get a good intro to AA and AAA accessibility guidelines:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/perspective-videos/contrast/

If you want to go beyond adjusting a few colors, here's deeper food for thought on designing for color blindness:

https://www.secretstache.com/blog/designing-for-color-blind-users/

Highlight takeaways are:

- Use colors and symbols to convey error messages.
- Add text labels to color filters and swatches.
- Underline links to differentiate between regular text and anchor
  text.
- Avoid using poor color combinations such as green-red and
  blue-purple.
- Use size, placement, or font weights to make primary buttons stand
  out.
- Mark required form fields with a symbol (such as an asterisk) or
  label them.

There's a neat tool that lets you preview any site through the lens of various color sight impairments. If you are able to stage your designs somewhere online, you can see your original version through Deuteranomaly, Protanomaly, and Monochromatic vision filters and adjust colors and contrasts as necessary:

https://www.toptal.com/designers/colorfilter/

[image: CNN.com through a color blindness filter]

There are many free color contrast checker tools out there to help you find a sufficient contrast range for AA or AAA compliance. There are two I like:

https://contrastchecker.com/

https://accessible-colors.com/

Comment: Thank you sir! I much enjoyed the first look at these and will study and apply to the designs.